# WiFi adapter is not found and no internet even on lan

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and when I go to Settings/Wi-Fi networks it says `There is no Wi-Fi adapter'

When I run `rfkill list all` I get

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

When I run `lshw -C network` I get

```
*-network DISABLED
  Description: Wireless interface
  Product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
  ....
```

Can someone give me a hand and help me to fix this problem?

Comment: DISABLED usually means that the wireless switch or key combination, sometimes called Airplane Mode, is set to turn *off* the wireless radio. Please find it and switch it. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all`

Comment: We need to dig a lot deeper to solve this. Please provide the result of the wireless script from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos As the result will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: well i dont know why but my `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` was full and that was i think the reason why i didnt had internet. it took me like 8 hours to find that out.

Comment: i manage to connect to the internet using those commands: `sudo ip addr flush dev wlp3s0`, `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down`,  `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up`, `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 essid [name of wifi network]` (i created a new hot-spot with my phone without password, `sudo dhclient wlp3s0`, where `wlp3s0` is the name of the wifi adapter you can get this name from `ifconfig -a`

Comment: So, you are solved and all set now?

Comment: Yes! As I said I think the problem was that's I didn't had any space, that's why most of the functions in Ubuntu we're not working. But this is just a guess.

Comment: Glad it's working!

Comment: @Dimitar Please post that as an answer below :)

Comment: @Seth i now saw the root of my problem. It was because a log files have constantly filling my hard drive and there were more then 20GB of log files and there is this folder /var/log/cups that was constantly filling with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to connect to the internet using only the terminal. I created a hot-spot using my phone without password. It is important to **be without a password**, because connecting to the terminal allows only WEP secured passwords, but my phone supported only WPA2 protected passwords.

1. `sudo ip addr flush dev wlp3s0` It is not a necessary step, but it will clean if there is any other connection already
2. `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down` Switched off the adaptor
3. `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up` Switches on the adaptor
4. `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 essid [name of wifi network]`
5. `sudo dhclient wlp3s0` Connects you to the wifi network from step 4

Where `wlp3s0` is the name of your adaptor. You can find out what is the name of your adaptor using `ifconfig -a`

You can check if you have internet using `ping google.com`

And finally i want to say that i do not had internet because my hard disk `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` was full with data and the whole system was not working currently. So you can check that was well. My problem was that `/var/log/` was full with data and I just deleted the whole log folder using 'rm -rf /var/log/` **IT IS STRONGLY RECOMMENDED NOT TO DO THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING!!!** IT IS ALWAYS A LAST CHOICE TO JUST DELETE THE WHOLE 'LOG' FOLDER JUST LIKE THAT! If you do this you will end up with a lot of problems and recreating the log folders of debs that need them for example: apache2, nginx, mysql... and so on. You have to create them after that manually and also deal with all the right rights for the folders and the files. So, be careful. It is recommended only to delete the deb of the log folder and then delete the log folder. I did that, because it was filling with data all the time and i had no other choice. Hope i helped.

BTW, you can check if your driver is installed running `sudo lshw -C network` and there should be this info

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 01
   serial: 74:c6:3b:d5:45:6f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.100.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:19 memory:9b100000-9b17ffff memory:9b180000-9b18ffff
```

> driver=ath9k driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic

Comment: one more thing i just deleted the cups `sudo apt purge cups` and i freed 25gb of space!

Answer (score 0):

As I think your WLAN drivers were missing.. becouse of that you shulod download drivers for network.

1. Step
   Lets Type in terminal as

> lspci -nn

2. Step
   Just now you can find what should down drivers.
3. Step
   *Now go to this site and downlaod what do you want*[wifi](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi)
4. Step
   plese follow step by step as they told.

**thank you**

Comment: When I run lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 I get this result: Kernal driver in use: ath9k , kernal modules: ath9k. That means I have the driver installed right?

Comment: Correct, they are. Please see my comment above.